# R: matching data.table columns as function parameters for a function applied to another data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I'm trying to scale some data for plotting.  Some of the scales might be provided by the user, and others can be derived from the data directly.

So a sample set of data might be:

```
dt1 <- data.table(Time=1:10, a=10:1, b=11:20, c=rep(11:15,2))
setkey(dt1,"Time")
```

And the ranges for plotting might be:

```
dt.ranges <- data.table(a=c(1,10), b=c(11,20), c=c(11,20))
```

The idea is for each `dt1` column, to scale the column by the matching 
name in `dt.ranges`.

I can do this using old-school data.frame style programming, but I'm wondering whether there's a quicker / more elegant data.table-oriented approach.

The clunky method that gives the correct answer is:

```
dt2 <- data.table(
  data.frame(
    lapply(names(dt1)[names(dt1) %in% names(dt.ranges)],
           function(nn,rt){
             print(nn)
             (dt1[[nn]] - min(rt[[nn]]))/(max(rt[[nn]]) - min(rt[[nn]]))
           }, 
           dt.ranges)
  )
)
names(dt2) <- names(dt1)[-1]
dt2$Time <- dt1$Time
```

The result:

```
            a         b         c Time
 1: 1.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000    1
 2: 0.8888889 0.1111111 0.1111111    2
 3: 0.7777778 0.2222222 0.2222222    3
 4: 0.6666667 0.3333333 0.3333333    4
 5: 0.5555556 0.4444444 0.4444444    5
 6: 0.4444444 0.5555556 0.0000000    6
 7: 0.3333333 0.6666667 0.1111111    7
 8: 0.2222222 0.7777778 0.2222222    8
 9: 0.1111111 0.8888889 0.3333333    9
10: 0.0000000 1.0000000 0.4444444   10
```

Does anyone know a better way?

Thanks

Jason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We get the `intersect` of column names from both the datasets (`nm1`) (assuming that the order of the column names are the same).  Specify the `.SDcols` as 'nm1', use `Map` to apply the function on corresponding columns of both the datasets and assign (`:=`) the results back.

```
nm1 <- intersect(names(dt1), names(dt.ranges))
dt1[, (nm1) := Map(function(x,y)
         (x- min(y))/(max(y)-min(y)), 
              .SD, dt.ranges), .SDcols= nm1]
dt1
#    Time         a         b         c
# 1:    1 1.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
# 2:    2 0.8888889 0.1111111 0.1111111
# 3:    3 0.7777778 0.2222222 0.2222222
# 4:    4 0.6666667 0.3333333 0.3333333
# 5:    5 0.5555556 0.4444444 0.4444444
# 6:    6 0.4444444 0.5555556 0.0000000
# 7:    7 0.3333333 0.6666667 0.1111111
# 8:    8 0.2222222 0.7777778 0.2222222
# 9:    9 0.1111111 0.8888889 0.3333333
#10:   10 0.0000000 1.0000000 0.4444444
```

If the columns are not in the same order

```
dt1[, eval(nm1) := Map(function(x,y)
       (x- min(y))/(max(y)-min(y)), 
        .SD, dt.ranges[, nm1, with=FALSE]), .SDcols= nm1]
```

Comment: Thanks! Slick use of Map().  I need to learn more about the functional programming aspects of R. I needed to use `eval(nm1)` in the "not in the same order" answer to make it work, and have edited the answer to show this.

Comment: @Jason It worked for me without the `eval`.  Can you try it on a fresh R session?

Comment: Just tried it on a freshly opened session, only package loaded was data.table, nothing in the environment. I still needed the eval() to produce the desired result. R version 3.2.3, Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit), data.table version 1.9.6

Comment: @Jason Just wrap with brackets i.e. `(nm1) := ` works for me.

Comment: Me too! Let's call the bracket-wrap canonical.  :)  Thanks so much for your help and insight!